# RethinkDB python query returns result different from data explorer

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I am running a RethinkDB using the Python driver.

**Python Request:**

```
response = r.db("user_data_sets").table("indexes").get_all(r.args(['key1', 'key2'])).run()
```

This request is only returning the `key2` record in `response`.

```
> len(response.items)
> result = int(1)
```

If I run the query in the [Data Explorer](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/reql-data-exploration/), I get both records.

**Data Explorer Test Request:**

```
r.db("user_data_sets").table("indexes").getAll(r.args(['key1', 'key2']))

2 rows returned. Displaying rows 1-2
```

I'm kinda at a loss here. Am not sure if this is a driver bug/issue, or a syntax quirk, or something else entirely. Google hasn't produced anything insightful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this and got the correct results:

RethinkDB Version:

```
rethinkdb 2.3.4 (CLANG 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31))
```

RethinkDB Python module:

```
rethinkdb==2.1.0.post2
```

Here's my Python code:

```
r.db("test").table("so1").insert({"id":1}).run(conn)
r.db("test").table("so1").insert({"id":2}).run(conn)
list(r.db("test").table("so1").get_all(r.args([1, 2])).run(conn))
# [{'id': 2}, {'id': 1}]
```

And the results in the WebUI

[image: example image]

If you create an entirely new table, and just insert these two documents. Are the results the same?

Comment: Yeah - I had just come across https://rethinkdb.com/api/python/to_array/ in the docs. That's exactly what they recommend for small sets. I think I was trying to use the cursor improperly

Comment: Let me know if you have any more questions @getglad!